# piece information

Tags: piece-information

I found a lego item that I can not fiugre out what it is or what set it goes with.  I was hoping someone out there could give me some info on the item. I'm attaching a picture of the item in question.  Its beige and blue the red buttons on the sides spin the what looks like blue legs at the end of it. [image: lego item][image: lego item 2]